# identifying a substring from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want a column to return `'Consider'` if the comment column contains the string `'True_Critical'` otherwise return `'Not Consider'`.

```
Comment                                            Result
True_Critical_Alarm - Confirmed with DB            Consider
True_Critical  - Confirmed with DBM                Conisder
True_Normal- Confirmed with DB                     Not Conisder
```

I used `df['cosider']=df['Comment '].str.startswith('True_critical')` but it did not work.

Comment: `np.where(df['Comment '].str.startswith('True_critical'), 'Consider', 'Not Consider')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.where` to fill in values in the *Result* column:

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df['Comment'].str.startswith('True_Critical'), 'Consider', 'Not Consider')
```

It allows you to substitute `True` and `False` values with values of your choice.

Comment: don't know how the above code is considering even '6366923011' in the comment section as 'Consider'

Comment: The code u mentioned could not capture all the desired data/ I found that using "str.contains('True_Critical')" to be more useful..However the following code also captures '6366923011' as Consider

Comment: @Harishreddy Sounds intriguing, can you provide a detailed example?